# How to assign a new variable two other variables' data?

Tags: php

I have two variables:

```
$getSkill = $_GET['skill'];
$avg = avg;
```

I have an 'averages.php' file included that has all of the necessary averages preloaded but this current PHP file is defined by `$_GET['skill']`, each average in there is loaded as `$skillnameAvg` and I am trying to echo the relevant `$skillnameAvg` to each dynamic page correctly.

I've tried `$getSkillAvg = $.$getSkill.$avg;` and a few others and I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Simple: `$getSkillAvg = ${$getSkill.$avg};` And must edit the value of `$avg`, It should be string.

Comment: can you please provide value of $getSkill = $_GET['skill'];
$avg = avg; variables , means wht value comes in $_GET['skill']; and 'avg' ?

Comment: you have to keep variable value like $avg='avg';

Comment: $_GET['skill'] can be vary from 30 different things, but for example's sake in one instance it would be 'hunter'. So $getSkill would be "hunter" and $avg would be "avg". Equalling together to "hunteravg" where the AVG variable included from averages.php is $hunterAvg. However Frayne's answer provided a solution, so thankyou anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Variables variables in PHP

```
$getSkill = $_GET['skill'];
$avg = $getSkill . 'avg';
echo $$avg;
```

Example

```
$chippyavg = '20%';  // create a testing value eg your included file

$getSkill = 'chippy'
$avg = $getSkill . 'avg';

echo $$avg;
```

Result

```
20%
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a big deal, but for you I can share some information. First of all you need to concatenate two variable `$_GET['skill']` and `$avg`, and make them also another variable by using a `$`sign prefix of the resultant value.

Now use `echo $getSkillAvg = ${$getSkill.$avg};`, what it shows? If you don't define the variable that is generated here then `E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined variable: skillavg -- at line 8`. Or if defined then the value will be display.

Now what you are trying to do make that value a variable, so do that you need to use another `$` sign before the resultant value. Then the result says undefined variable, so you need to make that variable as string to show as output as i do in below code.

```
$skillavg = 'Smith';     //assignment for work
$_GET['skill'] = 'skill';//assignment for work

$getSkill = $_GET['skill'];
$avg = "avg";

echo $getSkillAvg = "$${$getSkill.$avg}"; //$Smith
```